# I have a large mongo list. I have other mongo documents that need to keep sub lists references to that list in a dbref

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm keeping track of logs, and logs are bucketed out for faster reading.

something like (this is all in c#, really)

```
logs : [{ ts: 14423.., _id: ...}];

logbucket { subloglog : [id1,id2,id] }
```

I read some where that on a reindex object ids are changed. How can I ensure that id1,id2,etc will always reference the same records in logs?

If it will, what's the fastest way to pull the whole list up as a query (I have figured out pagination and that 1500 records is pretty ideal for my set up)?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: if I do something like reindex will my list of objectids beuseless or will the dbrefs be updated?